# How to add parent class attributes to sub class

Tags: java, oop

I have a parent class named `Set` representing a set of a tennis matches.

```
public class Set {
  private String set1;
  private String set2;
  private String set3;
  //private Object[] match;

  public Set() {
    setSet1(set1);
    setSet2(set2);
    setSet3(set3);
  }

  public void setSet1(String set1) {
    this.set1 = set1;
  }

  public String getSet1() {
    return set1;
  }

  public void setSet2(String set2) {
    this.set2 = set2;
  }

  public String getSet2() {
    return set2;
  }

  public void setSet3(String set3) {
    this.set3 = set3;
  }

  public String getSet3() {
    return set3;
  }


  public String toString(){
    return String.format("set1: %s, set2: %s, set3: %s", set1, set2, set3);
  }


}
```

and a sub class of `Set` named `SingleSet` where I try to add the sets into an array named `game.

```
public class SingleSet extends Set{
  private Object homePlayer;
  private Object awayPlayer;

  private String[] game;

  public SingleSet(Object homePlayer, Object awayPlayer){
    super();

    game = new String[3];

    game[0] = super.getSet1();
    game[1] = super.getSet2();
    game[2] = super.getSet3();

    setHomePlayer(homePlayer);
    setAwayPlayer(awayPlayer);
  }

  public void setHomePlayer(Object homePlayer) {
    this.homePlayer = homePlayer;
  }

  public Object getHomePlayer() {
    return homePlayer;
  }

  public void setAwayPlayer(Object awayPlayer) {
    this.awayPlayer = awayPlayer;
  }

  public Object getAwayPlayer() {
    return awayPlayer;
  }

  public void setGame(String[] game) {
    this.game = game;
  }

  public String[] getGame() {
    return game;
  }

  public String toString(){
    return String.format("Player: %s Vs. Player: %s, Single set game: %s, %s, %s", homePlayer, awayPlayer, game[0], game[1], game[2]);
  }
}
```

This is where I am trying to add the `Set`s from my parents class into my sub class (this is for FXML, so the code is in my controller):

```
 public void submit() {
    SingleSet game1 = new SingleSet(homePlayer1Dropdown.getValue(), awayPlayer1Dropdown.getValue());
    game1.setSet1(set1Box1.getText());
    game1.setSet2(set1Box2.getText());
    game1.setSet3(set1Box3.getText());

    System.out.println(game1);
 }
```

When I print the result, my array values are null. I tried printing them individually and that worked fine, so I know the `set1Box.getText()` is working fine.

Comment: `setSet1` and so on don't set values in your `game` array. They set `set1` etc.

Comment: It is is bad practice to have a constructor call the classes setters (as seen in the first class) have the values passed into the constructor.  Also I think your understanding of Tennis, lacks some what a Tennis Match is made up of a number of Sets, and Each Set is name up of a number of Games.

Comment: you might have to  @Override the toString method. and check your setter and your array . setters are for set1,set2,set3. you wanna print game[0..2]

Comment: Constructors are used to set values to instance variables. It is ok to use own setters, so you can have all the logic there (like reject `null` values) but you have to give your constructor's some parameters, like `public Set( String set1, String set2, String set3)`.
Then you should also change the `super()` call.

Comment: it is also not (always) good to have same data saved multiple times - harder to get them all synchronized. The `game` field is not necessary - if an array is needed, just change the `getGame` method to create and fill an array. (`public String[] getGame() { return new String[]  { getSet1(), getSet2(), getSet3() }; }`)

Comment: @Codekid no need to apologise for asking a novice question, many reviewers are beginners as well and it is fine for them to help you. I also format some of you code.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are seeing `null` values when you print is because they are actually `null`.

`SingleSet game1 = new SingleSet(homePlayer1Dropdown.getValue(), awayPlayer1Dropdown.getValue());` is creating a new `SingleSet`, which extends `Set`.

`SingleSet` constructor makes a `super()` call to Set constructor.

When Set is created for the first time, all its values are `null`. Then constructor kicks in, but Set constructor actually does nothing, so Set's instance variables remain null.

Ten SingleSet carries on on building your object with parameter given, which do nothing for setting a value for set1, set2, set3.

```
 game1.setSet1(set1Box1.getText());
 game1.setSet2(set1Box2.getText());
 game1.setSet3(set1Box3.getText());
```

They actually set a value to set1, set2, set3 (since you are saying that set1Box1.getText() and others are working). So why you are still seeing null when printing?

```
public String toString(){
  return String.format("Player: %s Vs. Player: %s, Single set game: %s, %s, %s", homePlayer, awayPlayer, game[0], game[1], game[2]);
}
```

That's why: you are printing game[0], and so on, that are actually null because when you set your game array, those values where null!

```
public SingleSet(Object homePlayer, Object awayPlayer){
  super(); //setting null values to set1, set2, set3

  game = new String[3];

  game[0] = super.getSet1(); //this returns null!
  game[1] = super.getSet2(); //this returns null!
  game[2] = super.getSet3(); //this returns null!

  setHomePlayer(homePlayer);
  setAwayPlayer(awayPlayer);
}
```

Print some values when you build your object and will see :)

To solve, one way is to use a parametrized constructor `public Set(String set1, String set2, String set3)`, use a parametrized child constructor `public SingleSet(String set1, String set2, String set3, Object homePlayer, Object awayPlayer)` and a parametrized call to super, `super(set1, set2, set3)`

Then you should set values when creating game1
`SingleSet game1 = new SingleSet(set1Box1.getText(), set1Box1.getText(), set1Box1.getText()homePlayer1Dropdown.getValue(), awayPlayer1Dropdown.getValue());`

Answer (score 1):

1. You are not setting anything in Set's default constructor
2. Should really find a better name for your class as "Set" is confusing with collections Set.
3. Make use of immutable for both of your classes to save yourself from trouble - remove all the setters and initialize in constructor.
4. I'm not that good at tennis scoring rules, but to my best knowledge a "set" has number of "games", and "match" consists from a number of sets. What is the logic for this relation "Set <- SingleSet"? What if you change your hierarchy in this way (in pseudo-code, will skip most method bodies for brevity):

```java
class Player{
  private String name;
  public Player(String name);
}

class Match{
  private Player homePlayer;
  private Player awayPlayer;
  private List<Set> sets;
  public Match(Player homePlayer, Public awayPlayer);
  public List<Set> getSets(){
    if(sets == null){
      sets = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    return sets;
  }
}

class Set{
  public Set(Game... games);
}

class Game{
  // game score details
  public Game(int scoreHomePlayer, int scoreAwayPlayer);
}
```

So that in your Controller, you could use it like this:

```java
Match match = new Match(new Player("Williams"), new Player("Johnson"))
match.getSets().add(new Set(
   new Game(6, 1),
   new Game(4, 6),
   new Game(7, 0)
   // etc.
))
```

5. You could further refactor #4 hierarchy and spare all these "new ()" constructor calls using [Builder Pattern](https://howtodoinjava.com/design-patterns/creational/builder-pattern-in-java/), something along the line:

```java
Match match = new MatchBuilder("Williams","Johnson").addSet()
  .addGame(6,1).addGame(4,6).addGame(7,0)
  .build()
```

Answer (score 0):

you should override set method .Instead of in the set after the constructor is instantiated

```java
 public SingleSet(Object homePlayer, Object awayPlayer) {
        super();

        game = new String[3];

//        game[0] = super.getSet1();
//        game[1] = super.getSet2();
//        game[2] = super.getSet3();

        setHomePlayer(homePlayer);
        setAwayPlayer(awayPlayer);
    }
    @Override
    public void setSet1(String set1) {
        this.game[0]=set1;
        super.setSet1(set1);
    }

    @Override
    public void setSet2(String set2) {
        this.game[1]=set2;
        super.setSet2(set2);
    }

    @Override
    public void setSet3(String set3) {
        this.game[2]=set3;
        super.setSet3(set3);
    }
```